# Can we change the content of the page without changing the url?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any option or any method , i have change content or form or move one page to another without refreshing the page or change in the url ..

My client want a single url after login and need all the functionality .

I m using asp.net with c# and this project is done

is this possible?

Comment: Use server.tranfer for redirecting one page from another page it will not change URL

Comment: Using a single `page` with multiple `usercontrols` is another option.

Comment: Either you can use ajax or you can use server.transfer

Comment: did you find your answer ? what did you choose to do ?

Answer (score 3):

You have several options Javascript, CSS or lot of C#

**Javascript**
Either you use Javascript to change the content of your page. In that case I advise you to use a Javascript Framework like AngularJS, jQuery Backbone ...
With javascript you will be able to manipulate the dom of your page and so to change the content.

**CSS**
This is the one option I not very confident in. You can display:none the content you dont want to display and change the visible part of your page as your user is clicking on content. It will require Javascript but wont be very dynamic

**C#**
Using variable POSTED to your unique Controller/Action you can choose which page to render in a Layout. *If you are using MVC.*

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use Server.Transfer("URL").

It wont change your URL.

Comment: That is working but when I click again (menu)it changes the URL on second click

Answer (score 1):

and you can try adding some jquery/ajax  - https://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

1. [Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) : Asynchronous data transfer and Dynamic DOM manipulation. Can avoid url change and reload but content.
2. [MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc)  : Model–View–Controller. Can avoid change of url but content